# autodiscover_tasks did not get the task under the django app

Tags: django, celery

When I use the following code to get celery tasks in the view file, I only get the tasks related to celery itself, but not the tasks under the django app.

```
from myproj.celery import app
print(app.tasks)

'''OUTPUT: 
{'celery.group': <@task: celery.group of myproj at 0x7fa640101940>, 'celery.map': <@task: celery.map of myproj at 0x7fa640101940>, 'celery.chain': <@task: celery.chain of myproj at 0x7fa640101940>, 'celery.backend_cleanup': <@task: celery.backend_cleanup of myproj at 0x7fa640101940>, 'celery.starmap': <@task: celery.starmap of myproj at 0x7fa640101940>, 'celery.chord': <@task: celery.chord of myproj at 0x7fa640101940>, 'celery.accumulate': <@task: celery.accumulate of myproj at 0x7fa640101940>, 'celery.chunks': <@task: celery.chunks of myproj at 0x7fa640101940>, 'celery.chord_unlock': <@task: celery.chord_unlock of myproj at 0x7fa640101940>}'''
```

The task of the current app will only be obtained when I use the following method.

```
from myapp.tasks import app
print(app.tasks)
```

Here is the celery file configuration

```
# celery.py
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myproj.settings')

app = Celery('myproj')
app.conf.update({
    'broker_url': 'redis://localhost:8000/11',
    'result_backend': 'django-db',
    'accept_content': ['json'],
    'task_serializer': 'json',
    'result_serializer': 'json',
    'worker_force_execv': True,
    'worker_concurrency': 10,
    'task_time_limit': 60 * 60,
    'worker_max_tasks_per_child': 200,
    'beat_tz_aware': False,
    'result_extended': True,
})
app.conf.enable_utc = False
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

This is the task in tasks.py under django app

```
from myproj.celery import app
@app.task
def add():
    x=1
    y=y
```

I'm confused, shouldn't autodiscover_tasks automatically discover all the tasks in tasks.py under django app? Why doesn't it look like it? How can I get it?

Comment: app.autodiscover_tasks(['myproj'])  does this help you?

Comment: I tried doing this and it didn't work, I also tried app.autodiscover_tasks(['myapp']) but it didn't work either